# Use bitcoin-qt for website integration?

Tags: website-integration

I have recently downloaded Bitcoin-qt and all necessary blocks, and have made some transactions, too. Now I want to use this to integrate it with my website. Is it even possible? If yes, then how?

I am planning to make an online store. If i can only access bitcoin-qt in my site, that will do the trick. I will manage to use the balance as I want. Just give a hint of what way I have to do.

Comment: You'll want to use bitcoind and the built-in JSON RPC API.

Comment: and how actully is to do it?

Comment: That is outside the scope of this site as the question is too broad. Do a web search for bitcoind json rpc tutorial, you will find resources.

Comment: You may want to check out the tag [tag:website-integration]. Perhaps after having a look around, you could edit this post here to narrow the topic to a specific question.

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you've changed the tag twice. It seems to me that you're still interested in discussing this topic. To that end, it would be helpful if you would refine your question instead of just changing the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best point to start with is: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro
Nothing much to say, just read and follow the steps.

Comment: thanks for the hint but i already seen this page and i can not find the jsonRPCClient.php file, i tried it finding in **google** and **github** but i didnt got any direct link or downloads on it.

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=json+rpc+php+client&oq=json+rpc+php+client

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable the json-rpc api for this.

You can enable it by adding the line : server=1 in you're bitcoin.conf

Here you can find the documentation: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)

I suggest you hire a programmer on how to intergrate it in your website.